# How to duplicate rows on DataFrame based on most recent row date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

My data looks something like this:

| Report Date | Location | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8/6/2021 | St. Louis | 100 |
| 8/1/2021 | St. Louis | 89 |
| 7/29/2021 | St. Louis | 85 |
| 7/24/2021 | St. Louis | 80 |
| 7/30/2021 | Louisville | 92 |
| 7/25/2021 | Louisville | 79 |

But when I plot the data in `plotly` using the built-in `animation_groups` and `animation_frames` the slider bar jumps from row to row by nature, which doesn't lead to an intuitive animation when each 'jump' is not the same amount of days.

What I'm trying to work-around and do is create a new table, which duplicates rows and keeps the true report data, but creates an additional 'animation date' to keep the slider bar transition intuitive. I'd like the new data table to look something like the below. Assume the date the code was ran was 8/6/2021.

| Report Date | Animation Date | Location | Data | Days Since Most Recent Report |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8/6/2021 | 8/6/2021 | St. Louis | 100 | 0 |
| 8/1/2021 | 8/5/2021 | St. Louis | 89 | 4 |
| 8/1/2021 | 8/4/2021 | St. Louis | 89 | 3 |
| 8/1/2021 | 8/3/2021 | St. Louis | 89 | 2 |
| 8/1/2021 | 8/2/2021 | St. Louis | 89 | 1 |
| 8/1/2021 | 8/1/2021 | St. Louis | 89 | 0 |
| 7/29/2021 | 7/30/2021 | St. Louis | 85 | 1 |
| 7/29/2021 | 7/29/2021 | St. Louis | 85 | 0 |
| 7/24/2021 | 7/28/2021 | St. Louis | 80 | 4 |
| 7/24/2021 | 7/27/2021 | St. Louis | 80 | 3 |
| 7/24/2021 | 7/26/2021 | St. Louis | 80 | 2 |
| 7/24/2021 | 7/25/2021 | St. Louis | 80 | 1 |
| 7/24/2021 | 7/24/2021 | St. Louis | 80 | 0 |
| 7/30/2021 | 8/6/2021 | Louisville | 92 | 7 |
| 7/30/2021 | 8/5/2021 | Louisville | 92 | 6 |
| 7/30/2021 | 8/4/2021 | Louisville | 92 | 5 |
| 7/30/2021 | 8/3/2021 | Louisville | 92 | 4 |
| 7/30/2021 | 8/2/2021 | Louisville | 92 | 3 |
| 7/30/2021 | 8/1/2021 | Louisville | 92 | 2 |
| 7/30/2021 | 7/31/2021 | Louisville | 92 | 1 |
| 7/30/2021 | 7/30/2021 | Louisville | 92 | 0 |
| 7/25/2021 | 7/29/2021 | Louisville | 79 | 4 |
| 7/25/2021 | 7/28/2021 | Louisville | 79 | 3 |
| 7/25/2021 | 7/27/2021 | Louisville | 79 | 2 |
| 7/25/2021 | 7/26/2021 | Louisville | 79 | 1 |
| 7/25/2021 | 7/25/2021 | Louisville | 79 | 0 |

By doing this, the animation could display 'Days Since Most Recent Report' or 'Report Date' to show that as the animation plays, some data displayed might have some antiquity to it, but the animation traverses through time appropriately and there is data displayed throughout the animation. Each time the 'Animation Date' matches up with a 'Report Date' a new bit of data will be displayed for each 'Animation Date' until a new 'Report Date' is hit and the cycle repeats itself til the animation is brought up to the present day.

If there is any easier way to work around this in plotly, please let me know! Otherwise, I'm having trouble getting off the ground with the logic creating a new DataFrame while iterating through the old DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can `reindex` through `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples`:

```
df["Animation Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Report Date"])

max_date = df["Report Date"].max()

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([[x, d] for x, y in df.groupby("Location")["Animation Date"]
                                 for d in pd.date_range(min(y), max_date)],
                                names=["Location", "Animation Date"])

s = df.set_index(["Location", "Animation Date"]).reindex(idx).reset_index()

s["Days Since"] = s.groupby(["Location", s.Data.notnull().cumsum()]).cumcount()

print (s.ffill())

      Location Animation Date Report Date   Data  Days Since
0   Louisville     2021-07-25   7/25/2021   79.0           0
1   Louisville     2021-07-26   7/25/2021   79.0           1
2   Louisville     2021-07-27   7/25/2021   79.0           2
3   Louisville     2021-07-28   7/25/2021   79.0           3
4   Louisville     2021-07-29   7/25/2021   79.0           4
5   Louisville     2021-07-30   7/30/2021   92.0           0
6   Louisville     2021-07-31   7/30/2021   92.0           1
7   Louisville     2021-08-01   7/30/2021   92.0           2
8   Louisville     2021-08-02   7/30/2021   92.0           3
9   Louisville     2021-08-03   7/30/2021   92.0           4
10  Louisville     2021-08-04   7/30/2021   92.0           5
11  Louisville     2021-08-05   7/30/2021   92.0           6
12  Louisville     2021-08-06   7/30/2021   92.0           7
13   St. Louis     2021-07-24   7/24/2021   80.0           0
14   St. Louis     2021-07-25   7/24/2021   80.0           1
15   St. Louis     2021-07-26   7/24/2021   80.0           2
16   St. Louis     2021-07-27   7/24/2021   80.0           3
17   St. Louis     2021-07-28   7/24/2021   80.0           4
18   St. Louis     2021-07-29   7/29/2021   85.0           0
19   St. Louis     2021-07-30   7/29/2021   85.0           1
20   St. Louis     2021-07-31   7/29/2021   85.0           2
21   St. Louis     2021-08-01    8/1/2021   89.0           0
22   St. Louis     2021-08-02    8/1/2021   89.0           1
23   St. Louis     2021-08-03    8/1/2021   89.0           2
24   St. Louis     2021-08-04    8/1/2021   89.0           3
25   St. Louis     2021-08-05    8/1/2021   89.0           4
26   St. Louis     2021-08-06    8/6/2021  100.0           0
```